# Is it worth putting a skill that is a prerequisite of a lot of other skills on my resume

Tags: resume, hiring-process, work-experience

One of the sections of my resume mentions a lot of different JavaScript skills I have.

For example:

> AngularJS, React, jQuery, Node.js, Express, PhantomJS, Tape etc...

That section just keeps going on about different skills and technologies I know in JavaScript and it's starting to get big.

I'm starting to think that almost anyone searching for an employee with **Node.js** or **React** skills would know that you cannot have those skills without **knowing JavaScript**.

So I'm asking is it a good idea to just **remove JavaScript** from that section?

Comment: You have no way of knowing how they process the resume, whether they do or don't pre-screen for keywords, and whether that screening is clever enough to recognize implied skills.

Comment: If you put JavaScript you could probably remove jQuery...

Comment: I would never make the assumption that someone who knows JavaScript knows jQuery.

Comment: You should tailor your resume for each different job application. Removing the irrelevant information *for that particular job*  will make it more likely that somebody will get to the relevant information before they stop reading and file it on the "reject" pile. If somebody has the task of filtering 500 applications in half a day, you can work out for yourself how much time they will spend reading each one!

Comment: Have different CV depending of who you are going to send it to. If you are going to send it to a recruiter, stuff it with keywords (5 years exp jQuery, 5 years exp JavaScript, 2 years exp Angular1, 3 months exp Angular2), etc...

If you know that your CV is going to a directly CTO, just explain how badass programmer you are.

Comment: This is a very technical approach to laying out a CV, most people doing the hiring are not technical. They employ someone to vet you at a technical level during the interview stage. A better approach would be "Competent in many modern advanced JavaScript frameworks and libraries", that then piques their interest to find out which match their needs.

Comment: I would actually make it the first item in the list: JavaScript, AngularJS, React... That would give the impression that you are very good with JavaScript.

Comment: Anecdote: A friend got a PhD in computational fluid dynamics, or CFD as EVERYONE calls. He got rejected by HR in several jobs because he had CFD written in his CV, so he didn't have the minimum required skills for the job, as he didn't know computational fluid dynamics. My point: HR has no idea of technicalities , if they have been asked for javascript, and they don't see it, they'll reject your CV.

Comment: @AndyLester And vice versa, if someone puts down jQuery, I wouldn't assume they *really* know javascript...

Comment: @Jasper - I've met quite a few people who can sling JQuery all day but don't even know it's javascript. You need to put both on the resume.

Comment: You're also forgetting that just because someone knows how to use all of these JavaScript frameworks that it means they know JavaScript itself. I've met more than a few developers who understand the basics of JavaScript and its syntax but are crippled without jQuery or other frameworks.

Comment: @alephzero no, it's too much work to have a dozen different resumes floating around. Someone "asks for a resume" and you need one right then and there, you lose track of which document your prospective company is looking at, you simply can't keep them organized, etc.

Comment: @camden_kid It is the first keyword in the list.  I just thought that the rest of the JavaScript skills on that list would be enough.  I guess it's not.

Comment: Adding hormones to Australian poultry was outlawed in the early 1960s, but the packets these days have a big "No added hormones" stickers on them. Your CV is your marketing - put things that sell on it, trivial or not.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It should not be a problem to keep it unless perhaps you're really running out of space. As many non-technical recruiters may be reviewing your qualifications, it wouldn't hurt to have it on the resume. I think for some, JavaScript may be more recognizable than say, PhantomJS.

Comment: I guess I'll just have to find another less important keyword in that section to remove. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'd even categorize all of those as "JavaScript expertise" - make that the heading and then list all the details.  It gets the hitword on your resume and collects the information nicely.

Comment: +1 and I agree with using a category of JavaScript as bethlakshmi suggests. I've actually had manager's, after I told them of my experience with Node/jQuery, ask if I have any experience with JavaScript. I've also experienced saying I have experience in JavaScript, and then the manager/interviewer say, "Oh, you've worked with Java?" As a specialist, remember: you are supposed to be the expert, so be friendly to people who don't exactly know what all the terms mean. Their checks cash just as well as anyone else's.

Comment: @bethlakshmi That would be a great idea if I had extra space on my resume. Unfortunately I'm asking this question because I need extra space and I thought removing JavaScript (and other keywords) would be a good idea because I thought it's obvious I know JavaScript if I have all these other skills.

Comment: It might be worth it to keep JavaScript in as long as you are skilled in native javascript. Many can use jQuery and/or other frameworks, but are unable to build complex apps in pure JavaScript. If this is your case, it might be good idea to mention "native expertise" as well

Comment: I made this exact same point to a friend recently; a lot of folks (or tools) reading resumes are doing very simple keyword searches, and don't know about relationships between technologies.

Comment: Lol. actually using PhantomJS does not even require knowing the JS -- it's just a tool with own API.

Answer (score 35):

Another factor is automated screening processes. You and any remotely technical recruiter/manager would know that Node.js or React implies JavaScript capabilities but if they never see your resume because the automated system filters out your resume it isn't going to matter.

It is always a good idea to make your that your resume specifically lists any requirements the job posting has and matches the way they list the requirement. Don't abbreviate or use an industry synonym or some skill that is a super-set of the required skills. If they want an expert in Widget 123 then list Widget 123 on your resume not Widgets 100-200.

Comment: Yes, what I was going to answer.  An ATS looks for keywords, it has no intelligence of it's own to link things together.  So if the job advert mentions Javascript, you need to have Javascript in your resume, or it's points against you.

Answer (score 25):

> So I'm asking is it a good idea to just remove JavaScript from that
>   section?

**No, leave it in.**

First, many non-technical recruiters look only for keywords given to them by the hiring manager. If the manager specifies "must know JavaScript" you want JavaScript to be included.

Second, a lot of software used by recruiters and HR is keyword-driven. So you want to match the keyword "JavaScript".

Lastly, leaving it off saves exactly one word. Not worth the risk.

Answer (score 10):

**Not everyone who reads your resume will have the technical expertise of the hiring manager.**

> I'm starting to think that almost anyone searching for an employee with Node.js or React skills would know that you cannot have those skills without knowing JavaScript.

That might be, *if* everyone that will read your resume is the hiring manager.  The hiring manager is probably only one person out of 5-10 that will look at it.

Scenario 1: HR clerk gets assigned the task of going and searching for resumes on the web, or a resume site like Monster.  Clerk reads your resume and says "This guy looks good, but he only knows React and jQuery, and we need someone who knows JavaScript."  Passed over.

Scenario 2: HR clerk searches Monster for "JavaScript", and your resume never shows up in search results.

Scenario 3: HR clerk is the filter on all inbound resumes.  He knows only to forward on the people who know JavaScript.  Rejected.

Scenario 4: It's time for a group interview, so the hiring manager hands out your resume to her superiors, or other members of your team who aren't programmers. "This person doesn't even meet the minimum requirements!" says the VP.

This applies to more than your JavaScript examples:

- If you know Rails or Sinatra, then also say you know Ruby.
- If you know Oracle or Postgres, then also say you know SQL.
- If you know Debian or RedHat, then also say you know Linux.
- If you know C++, and you also know C, then list them both.
- etc etc etc

Comment: two Scenario 3's?

Comment: +1 for "This applies to more than your JavaScript" this is way I asked this question because it applies to more than just JavaScript on my resume.

Comment: "If you know C++, then also say you know C." Please don't. These are two different languages.

Comment: @etarion: C++ is a [close superset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B) of C so the claim is not such a stress. If one was to be that precise, the Debian -> Linux implication is not correct either.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it's best to leave JavaScript in for an additional reason: the answer implies that you are familiar with and can work with plain old "vanilla" JavaScript, which sometimes you do have to do. Sometimes an employer for whatever reason isn't going to let you install an Angular or node.js framework on a site or even jQuery (I've seen it before, usually when the library impacts with something someone wrote for the site years before). Sometimes the job might entail "middle end" work that's neither directly involved with creating controllers and views or working with the back end per se. If you're familiar enough with JS, including its foibles, yes, you should list that.

The other issue here is that a lot of employers - maybe even the majority now - don't actually read your resume at first, they run it through a scanner looking for keywords and only come back to actually flip through it if the keywords are there. It's entirely possible that someone who needs a JS developer didn't bother to put Angular or React in as keywords because, I don't know, they don't actually use Angular or React for instance. If you don't say Javascript too you might miss out precisely because a human *isn't* interacting with your resume at the first level.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I consider this to be an excellent example of a more general principle.  In general, when communicating, you want to communicate in a way that will be understood.  That involves knowing your audience.  If you are applying to a local shop, with 6 current staff in total, named JavaScript Improvers, Inc., and you are customizing your resume which will be sent directly to the CTO, then you may be able to leave off certain information.  In general, knowing your audience is always helpful.  For most larger companies, as stated in other answers, you don't want to assume that your audience understands basic technical terms, pre-requisites, etc.  (They may be humans who don't know enough about some pre-requisites, or computer programs that may not have certain pre-requisites identified.)  As [Joe Strazzere's answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/71374/45088) mentions, you don't want to miss out on a common search term.

However, rather than just "leaving it in", and thereby mixing JavaScript with the other technologies, I have another idea: Removing JavaScript from that section might be a good idea.  At the same time, rename the section from "skills" to "other skills".  Then, separately, create another JavaScript section:

> JavaScript-Related Skills
>
> - AngularJS, React, jQuery, Node.js, Express, PhantomJS, Tape etc...
>
> Other Useful Skills
>
> - Infinite loops, buffer overflows, Heisenbugs, dividing by zero, off-by-ones, syntax errors, etc.

(The above example is just meant to demonstrate the basic concept.  Clearly **you'll want to customize** what is seen above.  Specific details on precisely how to do that can vary depending on other characteristics about your specific resume.)

Answer (score -1):

Many recruiters would not know.  For a sure a word search would not know.  Yes list it if you think there is a market.